# How to give form action to PHP Class

Tags: php

I have written class call  Users -> path:  class/users.php

and create login form in index.php

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <p>Email: <input type="email" name="user_email"/></p>
    <p>Password: <input type="password" name="user_password" /> </p>
    <p> <input type="submit" value="Login" name="login" /> </p>
</form>
```

as form action I want to call that class -> userLogin() methode  how to do that,

Comment: Are you using a framework?

Comment: form action doesn't call a function, it sends the values of the form to the page specified by action.

Comment: A class or a function called `userLogin()`? Classes are bound by braces, so it's hard to say what exactly it is that you want.

Comment: `if($_POST[login]=='login'){call login function OR define it here only}`

Comment: @FerozAkbar I was about to write something like that too, till I wasn't sure if OP meant a class or a function. *"as form action I want to call that class -> userLogin() methode how to do that"*

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I'm assuming his class is users from class/users.php and the method is userLogin() but without seeing the code it is hard to offer specific advice.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes you are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't make a form directly call a function.

The form action - or page that the request is being sent to on the other hand - that can call a function within a class - assuming that of course there is an instance of that class.

So for example, if you have a page with this - make the form action this page:

```
<?php

    if($_REQUEST['login'])
    {
        $users= new users();
        $users->userLogin();
    }

?>
```

At that point your class can go off and reference the global variables on its own - having said that, it's probably cleaner to actually send it the data it needs so that classes don't have to use globals:

```
<?php

    if($_REQUEST['login'])
    {
        $users= new users();
        $users->userLogin($_REQUEST);
    }

?>
```

This way, the class is certain that it has the information that is needed - and as an added bonus you can still call the `userLogin()` function even if you wanted to call if differently - like from a session, or cookie or through the help of a flock of flying unicorns - you get the idea.

The code in the form action doesn't even have to be much more than this. A user verification function will often send a redirect to the user - where to might depend on whether the user is successfully logged in or not.